# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returning cells in editing state in IOS 7

Tags: uitableview

The following problem doesn't occur in IOS versions prior to 7.

Using UITableView's slide-to-edit interface for deleting items, after deleting an item and scrolling, the newly displayed cell (returned from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`) looks like this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87749409/Screenshot%202013.09.27%2016.08.30.png

[That image may not be available forever, so here's a description: After scrolling, the new cell is still in the final edited state, with the DELETE button still visible and the cell contents off-screen to the left.]

Furthermore, the returned cell is even has its `editing` flag set.

The code I'm using to delete cells looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // Find the item that this cell represents
        NSDictionary *item = [self itemForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!item) return;

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [tableView endUpdates];

        // Remove it from the data store
        [Inventory removeInventoryItem:item];
    }
}
```

I was able to overcome this with a hacked solution. The code (with hack) is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    InventoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kInventoryCellID];

    // HACK - here we create a new cell when we try to reuse deleted cells. 
    // Deleted cells, when re-used, would still appear as if they were edited,
    // with the cell slid off to the far left and the DELETE button visible.
    while(cell && cell.editing)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kInventoryCellID];
    }

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[InventoryCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kInventoryCellID];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

With the hack (the while loop) a new cell is generated which is not in the editing state. This leads to a bit of wasted memory, but does produce the correct result.

I wonder if there is there something that I need to do in the `prepareForReuse` method to reset the editing state. Currently, my `prepareForReuse` method only initializes the controls inside (labels, etc.) with default values.

I've tried calling `setEditing:animated:` on both, the UITableViewCell and the UITableView when deleting the cell, in the `prepareForReuse` and whenever `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returned a cell that still had the `editing` flag set, but nothing seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had this issue, and the answer for me was a "doh" moment. Make sure you call the `super` implementation of `prepareForReuse` in your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks Leo, that was it! I hadn't thought to do that since I had been looking into this problem (along with a few others) for the past two days now and none of the implementations I ran across actually called the super's prepreForReuse (I just double-checked.) As penance, I'll post a note to those SO questions and blogs that they should do so.

Comment: Cheers! It says so clearly in the documentation, but indeed, rarely is it called.

Comment: BEFORE: "Why read the docs? I know what this does.. it's called in order to allow you to reset a cell to default values before reusing it." AFTER: "Hey doc, I've got this flat spot on my forehead..."

Comment: where do you mean i should call prepareForReuse?

Comment: In you own implementation of `prepareForReuse`, you should make sure to call `[super prepareForReuse];`.

Comment: omgggg. argh. :( @pauln i ran into the same thing, tried all the same steps as you, same result. thanks for posting.